# Django redirect with pk passed as argument

Tags: python, django

How can  django redirect work with id parameter?
Tired following but did not worked

```
return redirect('/invoices/status/',pk=est.invoice.id)
```

it matches to following urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.index,name='invoice_index'),
    path('insert/',views.insert_,name='invoice_insert'),
    path('<int:id>/',views.insert_,name='invoice_update'),
    path('delete/<int:id>/',views.delete_,name='invoice_delete'),
    path('status/<int:id>/',views.status_,name='invoice_status'),
    path('details/<int:id>/',views.details_,name='invoice_details'),
    
 ]
```

It generate following error

```
[name='home'] 
admin/ 
clientservices/ 
clients/ 
taxauthority/ 
vendor/ 
invoices/ [name='invoice_index'] 
invoices/ insert/ [name='invoice_insert'] 
invoices/ <int:id>/ [name='invoice_update'] 
invoices/ delete/<int:id>/ [name='invoice_delete'] 
invoices/ status/<int:id>/ [name='invoice_status'] 
invoices/ details/<int:id>/ [name='invoice_details'] 
estimate/ 
quotation/ 
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
```

if  `return redirect('invoice_status',pk=est.invoice.id)`

is used it gives following exception

```
Reverse for 'invoice_status' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 6}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['invoices/status/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

`return redirect(view_name_in_url,id=est.invoice.id)`

Comment: tried but it goes following error now Reverse for 'invoice_status' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 6}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['invoices/status/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$'] –

Comment: do not write `pk=est.invoice.id` , write `id=est.invoice.id`

Answer (score 3):

You need the code to be in this way:

```
return redirect('invoice_status',id=est.invoice.id)
```

Comment: tried but it goes following error now 
Reverse for 'invoice_status' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 6}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['invoices/status/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: What is the value of the variable `est.invoice.id`

Comment: it matches value in database which is 6. as pointed out in the above error

Comment: Make sure it is an integer.

Comment: If it is not an integer, typecast it

Comment: And also make sure, you write the same code as it is above